# Appending and Renaming File in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I've got a file
`sandeep_mems_SJ_23102003.txt` which needs to be renamed `sj_new_members_SJ_23102003.txt`

I'll be getting these files daily so its vital that anything after _SJ remain the same.

So far I've got the following:-

```
for each in `/bin/ls -1`;do
  sed -i 's/sandeep_mems_SJ/sj_new_members/g' $each ;
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` would help you if you were changing the contents of files. For renaming the file itself, you could do:

```
for each in *;do
    mv $each sj_new_members_${each##sandeep_mems_SJ}
done
```

I used * rather than /bin/ls because it avoids spawning an extra process and uses Bash's built in matching (globbing) mechanism.

Each filename is assigned to `$each`.

`mv` renames `$each` to `sj_new_members_` followed by the substring of `$each` that you want, using Bash's substring mechanism. More details on how to use Bash substrings are here:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Also, here's an alternative that uses the `cut` command, which splits along a specified character delimiter, in this case `_`. I don't like it as much because it spawns a new process, but it works. View the `cut` man page for more details. Note that `$(command)` is equalent to using backticks -- it runs a command in a subshell.

```
for each in *;do
    mv $each sj_new_members_$(cut -d '_' -f 3- <<< $each)
done
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. That would help you with contents of files, not the filename itself. Will re-edit.

Comment: Edited to better address the question. For your curiosity, though, regarding my original answer: when you use `sed s///`, anything on the left side (the search field) enclosed within `\(` and `\)` is available to be reproduced on the right side (the replace field) using `\1`. The parantheses are not considered part of the search. If you have multiple `\( \)` on the left side, then they become available as `\2`, `\3`, etc, counting from the left for each `\(` . These are called backreferences.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain how the modified version of code works?

Comment: Re-edited to include a better, all-bash solution and more comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
for each in `/bin/ls -1`;do
  mv $each sj_new_members_SJ${each##*SJ} 
done
```

The `##*SJ` is syntax for parameter expansion for removing everything up to the last `SJ`. Haven't tested the whole thing but it should work.

Comment: It's probably prudent to test code before posting because, as written, the output is `sandeep_mems_SJ_23102003.txt -> sj_new_members_SJ` which it not the wanted output.  It's missing `_23102003.txt` and should be: `sj_new_members_SJ_23102003.txt`

Comment: @user3439894. Nope, it works correctly. I did test the core line, just not the loop. Now i ran the loop two. Maybe you should have tested it before questioning it?:)

Comment: I did test it and copied and pasted the output above from the second test after adding `-v` to the `mv` command.  However I owe you an apology, I looked back through the command buffer and see where when I copied and pasted then changed the variable to a literal I missed the second occurrence, sorry! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename` utility:

```
rename 's/sandeep.*?_(\d+\.txt)$/sj_new_members_$1/' sandeep*txt
```

Comment: Would upvote because I learned something new from this and it appears useful, but not doing so because `rename` command doesn't appear to be available on BSD-type systems (or at least OS X), and the question addressed Bash generally.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your function as much as possible, so here's a solution that implements `sed`:

```
for each in *; do
    new=$(echo "$each" | sed 's/.*_SJ/sj_new_members_SJ_/')
    mv $each $new
done
```

I don't believe you actually need the `ls -1` command, as `sed` will change the filenames of those files that contain the requirements stated above.

In essence, what my command does is save the new file name in a variable, `new`, and then `mv` renames it to the filename saved in the variable.